# compute samples variance without loops

Tags: r, loops

Here is what I want to do:

I have a time series data frame with let us say 100 time-series of
length 600 - each in one column of the data frame.

I want to pick up 10 of the time-series randomly and then assign them
random weights that sum up to one. Using those I want to compute the
variance of the sum of the 10 weighted time series variables (e.g.
convex combination).

The df is in the form

```
v1,v2,v2.....v100
1,5,6,.......9
2,4,6,.......10
3,5,8,.......6
2,2,8,.......2
etc
```

i can compute it inside a loop but r is vector oriented and it is not efficient.

```
ntrials = 10000
ts.sd = NULL
for (x in 1:ntrials))
  {
  temp = t(weights[,x]) %*% cov(df[, samples[, x]]) %*% weights[, x]
  ts.sd = cbind(ts.sd, temp)
  }
```

Comment: Well, I explicitly requested you to ask new questions. However, as far as I am aware the answer to *that* question was already given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13553943/random-data-sets-within-loops/13554953#13554953 - only in words, not in code, though.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what type of "random" you want for your weights... so I'll use a normal distribution scaled s.t. it sums to one:

```
x=as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:20, 100*600, replace=TRUE), ncol=100))

myfun <- function(inc, DF=x) {
  w = runif(10)
  w = w / sum(w)
  t(w) %*% cov(DF[, sample(seq_along(DF), 10)]) %*% w
}

lapply(1:ntrials, myfun)
```

However, this isn't really avoiding loops per say since `lapply` is just an efficient looping construct.  That said, `for loops` in R aren't explicitly bad or inefficient.  Growing a data structure, like you're doing with `cbind`, however, is.

But in this case since you're only growing it by appending a single element it really wont change things much.  The "correct" version would be to pre-allocate your vector `ts.sd` using `ntrials`.

```
ts.sd = vector(mode='numeric', length=ntrials)
```

The in your loop assign into it using `i`:

```
for (x in 1:ntrials))
  {
  temp = t(weights[,x]) %*% cov(df[, samples[, x]]) %*% weights[, x]
  ts.sd[i] = temp
  }
```